# How to draw patent illustrations?

Tags: patent-drawings

My current organization provides support in the complete process of taking forward the invention disclosure till the last which is patent filling.

But I want some help in drawing patent illustrations which I can then attach as images in my invention disclosure document. Can anyone suggest good software paid/free which I can use to draw the illustrations based on my idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most patent illustrations are line drawings. As such, they are best created with a vector drawing program. Vector drawing programs edit graphic primitives such as lines and curves rather than pixels. For this reason, they can be easily rescaled and will always render and print out at high resolution. Commercial examples are [Adobe Illustrator](https://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html?sdid=KKQML&mv=search&s_kwcid=AL!3085!3!155829415152!e!!!!adobe%20illustrator&ef_id=VWM7IQAABahct2UN:20170925144755:s) and [Corel Draw](http://www.coreldraw.com/en/pages/ppc/coreldraw/?sourceid=cdgs2017-xx-ppc_brkws&x-vehicle=ppc_brkws&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-tKmncrA1gIV17rACh2smwq1EAAYASAAEgL6NfD_BwE). There are free options available such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) and [Gravit Designer](https://www.designer.io). There are many other options depending on your operating system. Do a search for "vector graphics software". Although you can do really colorful artwork with these programs, they work great for black and white line drawings. Other types of illustrations such as plots and flow charts are usually generated in appropriate corresponding applications. Mechanical parts are often created in CAD modeling programs such as [Solidworks](http://www.solidworks.com) or [AutoCad](https://www.autodesk.com/campaigns/original-autocad?mktvar002=709781&mkwid=sgYb1JMiD%7Cpcrid%7C199123816963%7Cpkw%7Cautocad%7Cpmt%7Ce%7Cpdv%7Cc%7C%7C&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=GGL_ACD_US_BR_SEM_EXACT%3EProspecting&utm_term=autocad&utm_content=sgYb1JMiD%7Cpcrid%7C199123816963%7Cpkw%7Cautocad%7Cpmt%7Ce%7Cpdv%7Cc%7Cpid%7C%7C&gclid=CPe0gr3LwNYCFQmmaQodY-EBSg). You should probably stay away from pixel editing software such as MS Paint or even Adobe Photoshop unless you are working from actual photographs.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of submitting Invention to your organization, you can give hand drawings or any drawings that you have (photograph or CAD drawings etc) your patent department will do the necessary drawings according to USPTO rules.

Comment: This is a good addition since companies with formal patent organizations are likely to redraw anything the inventor provides anyway.